# Windows 2012R2 VPN connects, can ping, but no shared drive access

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2

I have installed and configured the VPN Remote Access service on a Server 2012R2 box. The VPN connects fine. I can ping the server IP address. I cannot access any shares on the server using my windows 10 machine.

[image: Error Result for accessing server]

I have set the PTPP firewall ports, but could not see anything about GRE on the router. Netgear D6400 (which is up to date on firmware).
(For PPTP: 1723 TCP and Protocol 47 GRE (also known as PPTP Pass-through))

In research, I have seen it may be due to NAP policy, but I cannot see anything untoward in there.

I think it could be one of:
- Netgear router getting in the way. (have set DMZ to server, no effect)
- NAP blocking the connection (believe I set the policy to ignore people who didn't meet the health checks)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try disabling the Windows firewall temporarily, restart `netprofm` and check if the problem persists.

Comment: Done, but no difference, disabled Domain, Private, Public. Also tried disabling the AntiVirus software too.

Comment: Can you connect to a shared directory? Not the IP itself? Like `\\192.168.109.2\shareddir` or `\\192.168.109.2\c$`?

Comment: Unfortunately not. :(

Comment: Check the NAP and firewall logs, well, any involved logs really. If you can ping but not access shares, something is blocking SMB or CIFS or whatever.

Comment: Unfortunately I still have not had any success with this. I have turned Windows firewall off for public, domain, private. I have set the server as DMZ. I can RDP to the server using FQDN and IP. I can ping the server, just nothing when trying to access any shared resource :(